# Excel - Output number of selected columns that have fewer than 6 characters (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

Is there a VBA script that can output the number of cells in a selected range in Excel that contain < 6 (or <= 5) characters (regardless of if they are byte order marks  or BOMs)? The output can be in a popup, stored under the selected range, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim Kount As Long
    Kount = 0
    For Each r In Selection
        v = r.Text
        If Len(v) < 6 And Not IsEmpty(r) Then
            Kount = Kount + 1
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox Kount
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use a formula, if you don't want to use vba:

Example using rage A1:A14

```
=SUM(IF(LEN(A1:A14)<6,1,0))
```

This will have to be entered as an array function (using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>) - you will know if it is entered correctly, as excel will put `{}` around the formula

---

Example Data:
[image: example data]

---

Evaluating the array formula:
[image: evaluation steps]